# Why are 'beef' and 'pork' and 'mutton' used to refer to the meat of cows and pigs and sheep?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Why are 'beef' and 'pork' and 'mutton' used to refer to the meat of cows and pigs and sheep? Other animals keep the same name. Is it just some weird preference in the English language?

Comment: You probably want to say: "Why are 'beef' and 'pork' (and 'mutton') used to refer to the meat of cows and pigs and sheep?". "Why do A and B are used" is a strange construction to English ears, and in any language it's clearer to point out that you're talking about the words rather than the things they refer to.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1B8TwBrCIEY

Comment: not to forget *swine*

Comment: October 2012 on ELU: [Saxon vs French](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85638/normans-vs-saxons-cow-beef-sheep-mutton-chicken)

Comment: Just a side-note: In Czech, it's very similar, the common name of the animal has a different root than the name of the meat, exactly for these three: prase-vepřové (pig-pork), kráva-hovězí (cow-beef), ovce-skopové (sheep-mutton). As well, cows and sheep are almost the only animals where the word for him and her have a different root, it's therefore more urgent to have a separate word for the meat.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is fundamentally a class distinction.

With any given amount of land and labor, more food value can be created from growing grain and vegetables than from growing animals for meat. In the medieval economy, the local lord had title to all the land and had a large amount of labor at his disposal as a sort of tax on his peasant subjects. The lord could thus afford to invest a portion of that land and labor into growing meat for his table. But the ordinary peasant family, with only their own labor and a small allotment of land, could not afford meat; they instead ate grain and vegetables.

For a couple of centuries after the Norman Conquest in 1066, the ruling class of England spoke mostly French, and spoke of the meat they ate using the French words for the animals: *boeuf*, *porc*, *mouton*. The peasants whose labor went into raising these animals for their lords' tables continued to call these animals by their native English names: *cow*, *pig*, *sheep*. And the lexical distinction remained after the landlord class adopted English. They had spoken of the food for several generations as *beef*, *pork*, *mutton*; and there was no corresponding term in English for the food, since the English words designated primarily the animal.

Comment: The one animal commonly raised and eaten by peasant farmers was _chicken_, which doesn't have the distinction. Another example is _venison_ (from Norman) versus _deer_ (from Old English)

Comment: bear in mind whilst we do generally use chicken for both bird and meat, we also use the word pullet typically referring to a young chicken. Pullet = poulet.

Comment: But the French word *boeuf* refers to the cow's meat rather than the animal. AFAIK, the French word for the animal is *vache*

Comment: @Dónal I'm not knowledgeable in the history of the French language; but I believe that the base sense of *boeuf* is *steer, ox*, the castrated male, and that of *vache* is *cow*, the female. Certainly *boeuf* derives from Latin *bos, bov-*, which was the animal.

Comment: Worth noting that, in the UK, nearly all the meat from sheep is sold as lamb. Mutton is reserved for the meat of older animals and is rarely seen in most shops.

Answer (score 11):

'Beef', 'pork' and 'mutton' were originally the French words for cows, pigs and sheep. 'Cow', 'pig', and 'sheep' were originally Anglo-Saxon.

After the Norman Conquest, the French-speaking Lord would say 'Beef!', and the Anglo-Saxon peasant would go off and kill a cow.

This class distinction between the Germanic and Latin roots of modern English is all over the language. That's why it's rude to say 'fuck' and polite to say 'intercourse'. Although of course really well-educated people countersignal and just say 'fuck' anyway.

Comment: "Boeuf", "Porc" and "Mouton" are the words in French if you wanted to show that.

Comment: today, thanks to the Big Bang Theory TV show, well-educated persons say *coitus* :-)

Comment: D'accord Tristan, mais ch'sais pas les mots en Normande ancienne.

Answer (score -5):

There is no *reason* for it, it's just kind of a euphemism. If you've ever seen the movie [Babe](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112431/?ref_=nv_sr_2), you can understand why we don't want to think of our bacon as *pig*. I actually find it a more odd that we say *lamb* and *chicken* than that we say *pork* and *beef*.

Comment: Personally I think what's most odd is that we mix - we're not consistent. [StoneyB's answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/32569/6516) explains that though.

Comment: -1 Actually, as has been shown in the other answers, there _is_ a reason for it (and we have the French to blame).

Comment: Modern vegetarian ideology is the product of peoples in big cities loosing touch with the nature. They wouldn't even come to minds of people living when the language has formed.

Comment: -1 for inventing 'answers' if you don't know, don't answer. This 'funny' comment even doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @FolksLord Not so. While wrong, this is an honest attempt to answer the question and not an attempt at humour or irrelevant. Leaving the downvoted answer in place (as opposed to removing it) lets others with the same thinking know that it's not correct.

Comment: I've considered deleting it, as it's been debunked by the accepted answer. But I've left it, in the spirit of @EsotericScreenName's answer. I have to admit though, that I'm a little hurt by the mob mentality. Jeez guys, lighten up.

Comment: @FolksLord, I say the above (to EsotericScreenName) especially concerning your comment. It's not necessary or helpful get nasty. I wrote the answer thinking it was correct. I wasn't trying to be cute, English is my native language. My 47 years of speaking American English led me to the answer (as incorrect as it is).

Comment: This answer is not coming from a linguistic point of view--but from an intuitive one; inventing the premise that we would be using non-animal terms to dismiss ourselves from the reality of eating barnyard pals.  It then questions why we would do that for one animal vs. another: "if we use these words to sanitize our consumption of barnyard pals, why use 'beef' but then say 'chicken' on a menu."  Downvotes and explanations of reality are fine, but seriously @FolksLord - statements like "if you don't know don't answer" are borderline abusive.  Just correct the incorrectness without the attitude.